# Include Letsencrypt Root certificate in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to folllow [Azure Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) on how to get Api Management under a vnet and accessible through an application gateway (WAF). I'm stuck trying to upload the root cert into application gateway. It says that the "Data for certificate is invalid", apparently Azure Application gateway doesn’t like Letsencrypt certs.

My certs are:

1. mydomain.com.br
2. api.mydomain.com.br
3. developer.mydomain.com.br
4. managemnet.mydomain.com.br

I have used [acmesh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) to generate all certs:

```
./acme.sh --issue  -d mydomain.com.br --dns dns_gd    --server  letsencrypt
./acme.sh --issue  -d api.mydomain.com.br  --dns dns_gd    --server  letsencrypt
./acme.sh --issue  -d developer.mydomain.com.br ---dns dns_gd    --server  letsencrypt
./acme.sh --issue  -d management.mydomain.com.br --dns dns_gd    --server  letsencrypt
```

Vnet, Subnets, Security Groups and Api Management are all created successfully, all good except for the part I need to create the application gateway:

```
$appgwName = "apim-app-gw"
$appgw = New-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appgwName -ResourceGroupName $resGroupName -Location $location `
-BackendAddressPools $apimGatewayBackendPool,$apimPortalBackendPool,$apimManagementBackendPool `
-BackendHttpSettingsCollection $apimPoolGatewaySetting, $apimPoolPortalSetting, $apimPoolManagementSetting `
-FrontendIpConfigurations $fipconfig01 -GatewayIpConfigurations $gipconfig -FrontendPorts $fp01 `
-HttpListeners $gatewayListener,$portalListener,$managementListener `
-RequestRoutingRules $gatewayRule,$portalRule,$managementRule `
-Sku $sku -WebApplicationFirewallConfig $config -SslCertificates $certGateway,$certPortal,$certManagement `
-TrustedRootCertificate $trustedRootCert -Probes $apimGatewayProbe,$apimPortalProbe,$apimManagementProbe
```

The last line is where I need to inform the path to my .cer file. I have tried to add the mydomain.com.br.cer and fullchain.cer, no luck. Tried to use openssl to create a Base64 file, also no luck:

```
sudo openssl x509 -inform PEM -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem -outform DER -out trustedrootDER.cer
openssl x509 -inform der -in trustedrootDER.cer -out trustedroot.cer
```

I even created a VM running Windows [to try this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication), no joy.

The solution from the Architecture point of view is pretty simple, but the certs problem makes it troublesome:
[image]

Any direction here is much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you want to add the Lets Encrypt Root CA cert on your application gateway?

From my understanding the Root CA from Lets Encrypt is `ISRG Root X1` and this one should be already trusted by Clients (Browsers).You only want to add the Root CA if you have self signed certificates.

Here is a workflow with storing the certs in Azure Key Vault: https://techblog.buzyka.de/2021/02/make-lets-encrypt-certificates-love.html

Another Workflow here describes adding certs with ACME challenges: https://intelequia.com/blog/post/1012/automating-azure-application-gateway-ssl-certificate-renewals-with-let-s-encrypt-and-azure-automation

Comment: Thanks Philip. 
Honestly, I don't know why does the WAF requires a root cert. Is part of the tutorial and I followed it. I'm trying to recreate the whole thing without the root cert to see how it goes. In theory, the subdomains certs are available in the Api Management, so they would be presented to the client, right? The root cert would be useless. Also, there is no 2Way Ssl configuration between WAF and APIM, so I really don't know.

Comment: Azure Application Gateway only recognizes a few Certifying Authorities.
"Application Gateway trusts your website's certificate by default if it's signed by a well-known CA (for example, GoDaddy or DigiCert)."
Explore cert concatenation to get a trusted chain.  I used SSL Shopper to verify my chain was "green" in a third-party's view.

Sources cited:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates
-